# Poincaré-Hopf theorem using Stokes

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, alternative-proof

The [wiki entry on the Poincaré-Hopf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem) claims that it "relies heavily on integral, and, in particular, Stokes' theorem". However, in the sketch of proof given there which is more or less the one in Milnor's *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint* there is no integration.

Does the proof become easier by using Stokes' theorem? Is there a good reference?

Comment: Do you mean the WikiPEDIA article?

Comment: @t.b. Thanks for including the link

Comment: That wasn't me, I only fixed some typos :) You can see what was changed by whom by clicking on [edited *x time* ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/136250/revisions) above the last editor's name.

Answer (score 1):

In step 3 of the scketch you read "the degree of the Gauss map". Now one has to look for the definition of the degree of a map $ f:M\to N$. But that map gives a linear map in de Rham cohomology $f^*:H^m(N)\to H^m(M), n=\dim(M)=\dim(N)$. Stokes theorem says that the integral of $m$-forms induces an isomorphism $\int:H^m\to R$ an this transforms  $f^*$ (by change of variables in the integral) into a linear map $R\to R$. Such a linear map is the product times an scalar $d$: this is the degree of $f$.